# proof that involved limits of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to solve this problem:
proof or refute
$ \lim_{z \to 0}{f(z)}=0 \text{ iff } \lim_{r \to 0}{f(re^{i\theta})} = 0\hspace{3mm} \forall\hspace{3mm}\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$

I thought the claim is true and tried to prove it as follows:

let $f:D \to \mathbb{C}\hspace{3mm}$ a complex function, such as: $\lim_{z\to0}{f(z)} = 0 $

$\lim_{z\to0}{f(z)}\space\text{ iff }\space \lim_{z\to0}{Re(f(z))}=0\space and\space \lim_{z\to0}{Im(f(z))}=0$

$Re(f(x+iy))+i\cdot Im(f(x+iy))=f(x+iy)=f(z)=f(re^{i\theta})=f(r\cos{\theta}+ir\sin{\theta})=\\Re(f(r\cos{\theta}+ir\sin{\theta}))+i\cdot Im(f(r\cos{\theta}+ir\sin{\theta}))$

suppose that $\forall x,y\in D \space\exists r,\theta \space$ such that $z=x+iy=re^{i\theta}$
and $z\xrightarrow[z\to 0]{} 0\space$ iff $re^{i\theta} \xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0$

so to conclude $f(re^{i\theta})=f(z)$ iff $Re(f(x+iy))=Re(f(re^{i\theta}))$ and $Im(f(x+iy))=Im(f(re^{i\theta}))$

and that completes the proof

---

what do you think about it?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. Take, say,$$f(x+yi)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }y=x^2\text{ and }x>0\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then you don't have $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=0$, in spite of the fact that, for each $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$, $\lim_{r\to0}f(re^{i\theta})=0$.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Hi I didn’t understand why, this is a counter example to the statement